# Can't integrate Spring Boot Data with Neo4j

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data

I just started with Spring Boot Data Neo4j and trying to finish the movie tutorial. I got this [ERROR](http://pastebin.com/t6g2nFXq) but not really sure how to debug. Error summary : (1) Error creating bean (2)Could not autowire field. Any help, thank you.

My files structure as follows :

**SpringBootApplication.java**

```html
package com.test.springdataneothree;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.test.services.MovieService;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringdataneothreeApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
 
 @Autowired
 MovieService movieService;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(SpringdataneothreeApplication.class, args);
 }
 
 @Override
 public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("Main Spring Boot Class");
  movieService.countMovie();
 }
}
```

**Movie.java**

```html
package com.test.movie;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;

@NodeEntity(label ="Movie")
public class Movie {

 @GraphId
    private Long id;
 
 String title;
    int released;
    String tagline;
    
    
    public Movie() { }

 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String getTitle() {
  return title;
 }

 public void setTitle(String title) {
  this.title = title;
 }

 public int getReleased() {
  return released;
 }

 public void setReleased(int released) {
  this.released = released;
 }

 public String getTagline() {
  return tagline;
 }

 public void setTagline(String tagline) {
  this.tagline = tagline;
 }
    
}
```

**MovieService.java**

```html
package com.test.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.test.repositories.MovieRepository;

@Service("MovieService")
public class MovieService { 
 
 @Autowired
 MovieRepository movieRepository;

 public void countMovie() {
  movieRepository.count();
  
 }

}
```

**MovieRepository.java**

```html
package com.test.repositories;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.test.movie.Movie;

@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends GraphRepository<Movie> {
 
 Movie findById(long id);
 
 Movie findByTitle(@Param("title") String title);

 @Query("MATCH (m:Movie) WHERE m.title =~ ('(?i).*'+{title}+'.*') RETURN m")
    Collection<Movie> findByTitleContaining(@Param("title") String title);

    @Query("MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Person) RETURN m.title as movie, collect(a.name) as cast LIMIT {limit}")
    List<Map<String,Object>> graph(@Param("limit") int limit);

}
```

**MyNeo4jConfiguration.java**

```html
package com.test.configuration;

import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test"})
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.test.repositories")
public class MyNeo4jConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

 @Override
 public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  return new SessionFactory("com.test.movie");
 }

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-university is an example using the new spring-boot-starter for sdn

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with auto wiring: the annotation on the MovieService is wrong, it should be:

```
@Service("movieService")
```

or just

```
@Service
```

You are trying to inject a bean with the capitalised name, and the context can't find it (the injection is done by name). Another solution is to use the @Qualifier annotation on the auto wired field, like

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("MovieService")
MovieService movieService;
```